# How to extract keypaths from a javascript expression

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, expression, keypaths

Does someone know a method to extract paths from a javascript expression for use in a PathObserver like in https://github.com/polymer/observe-js ?

Polymer defines a path by

```
an ECMAScript expression consisting only of identifiers (myVal), 
member accesses (foo.bar) and key lookup with literal values 
(arr[0] obj['str-value'].bar.baz).
```

My aim is to observe all the paths that might affect the result of the expression (low 'observe' the expression). I was hoping for a simple regex, but code using js parsers like Esprima or Shift is fine too.

So a practical example: input is

```
'if (count(body.arms)/numlegs==1) head[0]=eyes[symmetry]'
```

and output would be

```
["body.arms","numlegs","head[0]","eyes","symmetry"]
```

Fast is better than perfect; the PathObserver would eventually tell me if the path doesn't validate.

Comment: I think a parser like esprima would be a much more reliable choice here than a RegExp (if the latter is even reliably possible).

Comment: Thanks for the link .. http://http://esprima.org/ ! Less thanks for the downvote, if that was you :-)

Comment: And another one http://shift-ast.org/parser.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this now. It may not be complete, and it may not be optimally fast, but it does what I wanted: take an expression and return observable paths for Observe.js (https://github.com/polymer/observe-js) . It uses esprima (http://esprima.org) to parse the expression.

```
Parser = {

    // requires esprima.
    // @see http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html

    outerscope  : 'window',

    getObservablePaths :    function(expression) {
        console.log('Parser.getPaths',expression);
        var ast = esprima.parse(expression);
        if (ast) {
            console.log('Parser.getPaths',ast);
            var paths = new Array();
            this.recurseObservablePaths(ast,paths);
            return paths;
        } else return false;
    },

    recurseObservablePaths  : function(tree,paths,path) {

        if (!tree || !paths) return false;
        if (tree.type =='Identifier') {

            // some sort of global
            console.log('Parser.recurseObservablePaths','adding identifier '+tree.name);
            paths.push({object:this.outerscope,path:tree.name});

        } else if (tree.type =='MemberExpression') {

            // member expression


            if (tree.property.type=='Identifier' || tree.property.type=='Literal') {

                // like foo[bar][24].quz ; the property is 'quz'
                // dabble down the object to get the path

                if (tree.property.type=='Identifier') {
                    path = (path)?'.'+tree.property.name+path:'.'+tree.property.name;
                } else {
                    path = (path)?'['+tree.property.raw+']'+path:'['+tree.property.raw+']';
                }

                if (tree.object.type=='Identifier') {

                    // like foo.bar ; were done with this path - push !
                    console.log('Parser.recurseObservablePaths','adding path '+tree.object.name+path);

                    if (path.indexOf('.')===0) {
                        paths.push({object:tree.object.name,path:path.substring(1)});
                    } else {
                        paths.push({object:this.outerscope,path:tree.object.name+path});
                    }

                } else {
                    if (tree.object.type=='MemberExpression') {

                        // like foo.bar.quz ; recurse the object
                        console.log('Parser.recurseObservablePaths','recursing member expression ..');
                        this.recurseObservablePaths(tree.object,paths,path);                        

                    } else {

                        // like foo(bar).quz ; the object is something weird. 
                        // ignore the property .. but recurse the object
                        this.recurseObservablePaths(tree.object,paths); 

                    }
                }
            } else {

                // the property is some sort of thing itself:

                if (tree.object.type=='Identifier') {

                    // like foo[bar.quz] - push the object, recurse the property
                    console.log('Parser.recurseObservablePaths','adding identifier '+tree.object.name);
                    paths.push({object:this.outerscope,path:tree.object.name});
                    this.recurseObservablePaths(tree.property); 

                } else {

                    // like foo.bar[quz(raz)] ; recurse both
                    console.log('Parser.recurseObservablePaths','recursing member expression ..');
                    this.recurseObservablePaths(tree.object,paths); 
                    this.recurseObservablePaths(tree.property,paths);   


                }

            }

        } else if (tree.type=="CallExpression") {

            // like foo.bar(quz.baz) ; we only want the arguments
            this.recurseObservablePaths(tree.arguments,paths);

        } else if (tree.type=="AssignmentExpression") {

            // like foo.bar=baz*quz ; we only want the right hand
            this.recurseObservablePaths(tree.right,paths);

        } else {

            // unknown garbage. dig deeper.
            var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(tree);
            for (var pc=0; pc<props.length; pc++) {
                var key = props[pc];
                if (typeof tree[key] == 'object') {
                    if (Array.isArray(tree[key])) {
                        for (var kc=0;kc<tree[key].length;kc++) {
                            console.log('Parser.recurseObservablePaths','recursing '+key+':'+kc);
                            this.recurseObservablePaths(tree[key][kc],paths);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('Parser.recurseObservablePaths','recursing '+key);
                        this.recurseObservablePaths(tree[key],paths);

                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('Parser.recurseObservablePaths','ignoring '+key);
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Try it ..

```
Parser.getObservablePaths('alert(life.and[42].the); universe=everything.else')

[{"object":"life","path":"and[42]"},{"object":"everything","path":"else"}]

Parser.getObservablePaths('if (count(body.arms)/numlegs==1) head[0]=eyes[symmetry]')

[{"object":"body","path":"arms"},{"object":"window","path":"numlegs"},{"object":"eyes","path":"symmetry"}]
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome !